# Free air or waveguide wavelength?

Tags: microwave

If you have a microwave frequency of say 2.45 GHz, would you use that frequency in a simple rectangle cross section waveguide, or do you need to use the "lamdba g" waveguide frequency I've read about and if so, why?

I don't understand why you specify one frequency (2.45 GHz)  but possibly calculate for another?

Comment: A link to what you have read about appears necessary to be able to make an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You use the guide wavelength. This is because the wavelength in the waveguide is different than the wavelength in free space. When a wave travels through the waveguide its wavelength changes. You need to solve Maxwell’s equations with the appropriate boundary conditions in order to determine what the wavelength will be in a specific waveguide.

The frequency remains the same. Saying “lambda g frequency” does not make much sense, because lambda g is the wavelength. You use the wavelength not the frequency.

Comment: Thanks. I'm completely new to microwave engineering. I never studied microwave or RF when I did Elec Eng 30 years ago, so its a steep learning curve. I have a copy of Pozar 4th Ed but sometimes you just need to ask newbie questions so you head off in the right directions. What I was trying to work out was "Where would I find a 1/4 wavelength location in a simple WR430 waveguide?" FUnny how the simple stuff can mess you up.....  :-)